# How to mock ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient for unit testing?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, azureservicebus

Using Java and SpringBoot, I am trying to create a unit test for a method that uses a ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient, but Mockito is not able to create the Mock because the class is a final class.

```
@Mock
private ServiceBusReceiverFactory factory;

@Test
void test() {
    ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient mockedReceiver = Mockito.mock(ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.class)
    when(this.factory.getClient()).thenReturn(mockedReceiver);
 
    consumer.listen(ack);
    //calls the ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.receivedMessages() that calls ack.

    verify(ack, atLeastOnce().success());
   

}
```

Comment: Mockito version?

Answer (score 1):

[Mocking final types, enums and final methods (Since 2.1.0)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final)

> Mockito now offers support for mocking final classes and methods by default. This is a fantastic improvement that demonstrates Mockito's everlasting quest for improving testing experience. Our ambition is that Mockito "just works" with final classes and methods. Previously they were considered *unmockable*, preventing the user from mocking. Since 5.0.0, this feature is enabled by default.
> This alternative mock maker which uses a combination of both Java instrumentation API and sub-classing rather than creating a new class to represent a mock. This way, it becomes possible to mock final types and methods.
>
> In versions preceding 5.0.0, this mock maker is **turned off by default** because it is based on completely different mocking mechanism that required more feedback from the community. It can be activated explicitly by the mockito extension mechanism, just create in the classpath a file `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing the value `mock-maker-inline`.
>
> As a convenience, the Mockito team provides an artifact where this mock maker is preconfigured. Instead of using the *mockito-core* artifact, include the *mockito-inline* artifact in your project. Note that this artifact is likely to be discontinued once mocking of final classes and methods gets integrated into the default mock maker.